# What's the difference between string.split(",", -1) and string.split(",",-4) in ruby?

Tags: ruby

The [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) for the String class's `split` method state:

> [If limit is] negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.

So as far as I can tell there is no difference between any of the following:

```
string="1,,2,3,,,4,,5,,6"

string.split(",", -1)
string.split(",", -4)
string.split(",", -1000000)
```

They all return the same value: `["1", "", "2", "3", "", "", "4", "", "5", "", "6"]`

Just wondering why it would be possible to assign different negative limits in this way.

Also, what happens if I do want to remove the trailing null values (like whitespace)? I know I can do `string.strip.split(",",-1)` but is there a way to do it without using `strip` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By both your testing and your quoted documentation, there appears to be no difference between `string.split(",", -1)` and `string.split(",", -4)`. The specification says there is no difference and you found no difference in testing. Hooray.

But note that `string.strip.split(..)` won't remove the trailing null values:

```
irb(main):003:0> string="1,,2,3,,,4,,5,,6,,,"
=> "1,,2,3,,,4,,5,,6,,,"
irb(main):004:0> string.split(",", -1)
=> ["1", "", "2", "3", "", "", "4", "", "5", "", "6", "", "", ""]
irb(main):005:0> string.strip.split(",", -1)
=> ["1", "", "2", "3", "", "", "4", "", "5", "", "6", "", "", ""]
```

You'll have to pick another mechanism to strip the nulls.

Comment: thanks, I was confused between nulls and whitespace. I get it now, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Ruby often has more than one way to do the same thing, even down to syntax.  Just make a convention in your code to use `-1`.

Are you asking how to have no limit, but do the null field suppression?  You can omit the limit parameter, per the docs.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought about just removing the limit.